# Subsetting dataset vs Subsetting survey design object

Tags: r, subset, stderr, survey

I´m analyzing a couple of survey questions with the `survey package`. Since the questions of interest have only been asked in some of the data collection periods, I only need a subset of the entire dataset. Interestingly, the following two approaches yielded slightly different results:

- #1: Construct a survey design object for the entire dataset, update it with the periods of interest as grouping variable, and then run the analyses for the defined periods.
- #2: Select only observations for the periods of interest, construct a survey design object for this subset, and then run the analyses on it.

For instance, when performing a design-based Wilcoxon test, the `t-statistic` and the `p-value` are slightly different in the two approaches. Why is that? And which one is more "correct"?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2021/07/22/subsets-and-subpopulations-in-survey-inference/

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered on CrossValidated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411026/why-it-is-important-to-make-survey-design-object-svydesign-function-in-r-with-i) (and in a bit more detail off-site [here](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2021/07/22/subsets-and-subpopulations-in-survey-inference/), as the comment says)

If the approaches give different answers, you want #1